# What is the minimal css for a navigation bar

Tags: css, navigationbar

With the advent of the 'nav' tag I'm revisiting the creation of a navigation bar. There are many tutorials but they take different approaches and cloud the issue with too much css.

Specifically, I have a 960 width content area and I want to centre the nav buttons within this.

1. Does the 'nav' element have any inherent css-behaviour, or is it purely a semantic-container?
2. If I'm centre-ing the buttons then surely I don't need to 'float' them? Text-align, centre for the ul should do the trick.
3. If I want the buttons to be shorter than the nav-bar itself, should I give the bar a height (using line-height for the buttons to centre them) or add margins to the buttons to push the bar outwards (vertically)?

Comment: Why dont you try... jsfiddle.net and come to us with some problems :p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a fiddle with a few examples: http://jsfiddle.net/joplomacedo/ejSby/

**Does the 'nav' element have any inherent css-behaviour, or is it purely a semantic-container?**

The `nav` element is a purely semantic container. In terms of css it behaves as nothing more than a simple block level element like `div`.

**If I'm centering the buttons then surely I don't need to 'float' them? Text-align, center for the ul should do the trick.**

If you,re using an `ul`, like you're saying you do, than you'll need the `li`'s too. The problem is `li`'s have a display of block (actually, not block - `list-item`. In the ways we're interested in, they behave like block though) - and when you want to put block level elements side by side, then you'll always either need to `float` them, or change their display to `inline` (`inline-block`).

Either 'floats', or 'inline-blocking'. I tend to prefer using the "inline-block technique" for many reasons - one of them is that, centering the blocks, as you want to, is just a matter of setting text-align to center on the parent element.

**If I want the buttons to be shorter than the nav-bar itself, should I give the bar a height (using line-height for the buttons to centre them) or add margins to the buttons to push the bar outwards (vertically)?**

It seems simpler to add `padding-top` & `bottom` to the nav block, doesn't it?

So again, here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/joplomacedo/ejSby/